# JQuery event $(document).ready doesn't fire with mobile safari on IPhone 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I use $(document).ready to fire the event. However, it works fine with IPHONE4S and IPHONE5S(both runs 7.1.1). But on IPHONE5(7.1.1), it doesnt fire at all.

When i change to window.onload, all work fine.

This confused me as all the IPhones are running exactly the same iOS. Why only IPHONE5 doesn't work with $(document).ready? Is this a bug of JQuery or iOS?

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    alert("fired");
});

window.onload=function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
    alert("fired");
}
```

Comment: Use Safari's Developer menu to access the console and see if the device's browser is throwing any warnings or errors.

Comment: Is there developer menu on the mobile safari on IPHONE?

Comment: Yes, it's accessible by tethering your device via USB and selecting its option in the Developer menu on your Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the jQ plugin jQuery mobile or an older version of jQuery. jQ 1.6+ is known to cause problems on Safari/iPhone. I think it isn't a "bug", rather some special support of mobile devices is outsourced to a plugin in order to keep the the core slim.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? How is jQuery mobile supposed to help? What's the code that would replace $(document).ready(...) when using jQuery mobile? Or do you just add jQueryMobile and it ensures that $(document).ready() will work on iPhone? And what if you need the same page to work both on desktop and mobile?

Comment: And could you point to some source regarding "jQ 1.6+ is known to cause problems on Safari/iPhone" (documentation, bugtracker and the like) that is relevant to the issue at hand?